# Custom expandable jquery bootstrap accordian animation breaks in chrome/works in ff.

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

**The problem**

I have tried endlessly to get this accordion section of my site to be cross-browser compliant/resonsive. The expandable accordion in this demo on firefox works just like it should:
http://www.kinetik.us/test.php
but when you try it in chrome the second item down's width doesn't calculate properly. I just cant seem to wrap my head around why this is happening only in chrome.

I have this code for each accordian that opens:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#collapse_link1').click(function() {
  if($('#collapse1').hasClass('in')){
    $('#collapse1').animate({ padding: 0 }).delay(100).removeClass('visible');
    }else{
        $('#collapse1').animate({ padding: "0px 20px 20px 20px" });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#collapse1').addClass('visible');
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

});

Any idea would be much help, as i am learning jquery very fast, but little bugs tend to cause me to get stuck! Heh! Anyways hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the link that you provided, as nothing loads, except the html.

Given what you've provided, I've mocked something up quick in a fiddle.  Let me know if this is on the right track of what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/U6Y9b/

```
    if($('#collapse1').hasClass('in')){

        $('#collapse1').stop(true, false).animate({ padding: 0 }).delay(100).removeClass('in');

    } else {

        $('#collapse1').stop(true, false).animate({ padding: "0px 20px 20px 20px" });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#collapse1').addClass('in');
        }, 1);

    }
```